# Determine all positive integer c such that f(c) is even

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have tried but couldn't approach it.

Comment: The question seems to be interesting..

Comment: The centers of a and b create a rhombus. Diagonals are perpendicular. Try Pythagoras.

Comment: This is possible if for a given value of $c$, there are even number of pairs of $(a, b)$ for which $(a+b)^2 = (a+c)^2 + (b+c)^2$. For example, $c = 2$. We get two pairs of $(a, b) : (4, 6)$ and $(3, 10)$ such that $(4+2)^2 + (6+2)^2 = (4+6)^2$ and $(3 + 2)^2 + (10+2)^2 = (3 + 10)^2$.

Comment: @ Math Lover,  can you post a complete solution